# How to debug JavaScript in IOS Action App Extension?

Tags: javascript, ios

With iOS, [Action App Extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Action.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH13-SW1), one could run a JavaScript code against HTML. However, after quite some search on Google, I have not found any document explaining how to debug in this situation (insert a break point or simply add/view console out statement).

Comment: I guess if I could not do that, is there a way to simulate/run/debug my javascript against documents in mobile safari? Thanks.

Comment: Created a related question on stackoverflow  [Debug an External Javascript against Documents inside Mobile Safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38624571/debug-an-external-javascript-against-documents-inside-mobile-safari)

Comment: I am looking for the same thing. found nothing yet :/

Answer (score 4):

It's not too hard, although recently I've had an issue with the page showing up when connected to the simulator.  In that case I just ended up using my phone directly. (Apparently you need to start desktop Safari after the iOS Simulator has started to inspect "remote" Simulator sessions)

- Ensure that on the device `Settings->Safari->Advanced->Web Inspector` is on
- (Make sure you've Trusted the computer from the device)
- Start MobileSafari on your device by running from Xcode and choosing Safari 
  -- this isn't necessary but you can decode the iOS Objective-C/Swift code as well.  You can just start MobileSafari manually and it will be visible in desktop Safari.
- Start Safari on your desktop, make sure `Show Develop menu in menu bar` is on in `Preferences`.
- In the `Develop` menu you will see your device name, say 'BSharer's iPhone'
- select the page name underneath your device name, say 'en.m.wikipedia.org - Wikipedia'.

You are now debugging that device page on your desktop.

There are options to 'Automatically start debugger etc...', but I've found that when I tried these my code would not execute.

You can't place debugger statements in the app extension JavaScript as it isn't injected until your App Extension starts.  Instead I would add a `debugger;` statement to my app extension JavaScript code which will pause the debugger in the app extension JavaScript code at the `debugger;` statement.

Start your app extension by selecting it in the `Share` menu, set any other breakpoints you are interested in, then hit the continue button on the debugger.

You will also catch uncaught exceptions of course.

The official documentation for this is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html).

**Make sure you remove the `debugger;` line from production code.**

Comment: This is identical to how you debug any JavaScript code on iOS.  I've done similar things with Meteor/Cordova apps.  You don't need to start from Xcode in that case of course.

Comment: Probably because I answered months after this was posted.  It's all good, thanks though.